# Getting the value from the first row where column name is <value>

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a form where a user inserts some values
[image]

When the user clicks the "ok" button Access makes a new table to save the values from disappearing when the form closes.

```
strSQL = "CREATE TABLE tblTempProjectGegevens (Project varchar(32),ProjectNummer varchar(32), Opdrachtgever varchar(32));"

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTempProjectGegevens (Project, ProjectNummer, Opdrachtgever)" & _
         "VALUES ('" & ProjectInvoer.Value & "', '" & ProjectNrInvoer.Value & "', '" & OpdrachtgeverInvoer.Value & "');"

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)   

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMain", acNormal, , , acFormAdd
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmProjectInvoer", acSaveNo
```

I save these values in a table, because my program requires the form to be closed.

[image]

When the user is done using my access file, there are some reports to be printed. On these reports are headers in wich I want the values I have saved in the temp table.

[image]

How do I get the values from the table in my report headers? During a report_load() event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel as Integer)
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("tblTempProjectGegevens")

Me.Project.Value = rec("Project")
Etc...

End Sub
```